# Get two polymorphic relationship results together

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

[From the Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships) - if I have this many-to-many polymorphic relationship:

```
class Tag extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Post', 'taggable');
    }

    public function videos()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany('Video', 'taggable');
    }

}
```

So I can do this:

```
$tag = Tag::find(1);
$posts = $tag->posts;
$videos = $tag->videos;
```

How could I get all the tags relationships as one result? i.e. in a one-to-many polymorphic relationship you do this:

```
$tag = Tag::find(1);
$taggable = $tag->taggable;
```

But that doesnt seem to work for me in the many-to-many relationship - I get this SQL error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tag_groups.'
>   in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `tag_groups` where
>   `tag_groups`.`` is null limit 1)

Comment: What result you expect it to be? Eloquent Collection is rather not the way to go, since you can have key duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to merge the results yourself:

```
$taggable = $tag->posts->toBase()->merge($tag->videos);
```

This'll return an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection`.

An Eloquent collection does not make sense in this context.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get all relations in one result but you may load them all eagerly using something like this:

```
$tag = Tag::with(['posts', 'videos'])->find(1);
$relations = $tag->getRelations();
```

Here `$tag->getRelations()` will return an array of loaded relations so you may access one using something like this:

```
$posts = $relations['posts']; // Collection of Post models
$videos = $relations['videos']; // Collection of Video models
```

You can merge them like:

```
$allRelations = array_merge($posts->toArray(), $videos->toArray());
```

Or using `merge` method of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` (As `Joseph Silber` mentioned)

```
$allRelations = $relations['posts']->toBase()->merge($relations['videos']);
```